# Display Handlebars.js context in a template

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a variable passed into every handlebar.js template that contains all the context content that is accessible by the template?

e.g. I'm creating a template, but I don't know all the context content accessible by the template. I want to be able to type into the template `{{ debug }}` and handlebars.js will spit out all the context content into the HTML

Comment: You mean like [this](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks/)?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Yes! Why didn't you post that as an answer?!

Comment: No big deal, it's not really an *answer*. I'm glad it helps.

Comment: The solution in the link does not return the data, does anyone have a reliable way to view access context data within a template?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code to iterate through `this` object:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

or a similar piece of code iterating through `@root` object:

```
{{#each @root}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Handlebars has built-in helper `log`.

You just need to set [logging level](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/7172d167ddf9cbf1e8a0aae48970da42107e9e59/lib/handlebars/base.js#L205) to **DEBUG**.

```
Handlebars.logger.level = 0;
```

Then use helper:

```
{{log this}}
```

EDIT: Sorry, this will not write context to *HTML*, helper uses *console.log*. For outputting to HTML you need to write custom helper that will use for example [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is somewhat old, someone might find this usefull. You can just dump the handlebars current context into plain text with;

```
{{{.}}}
```

Comment: I tried this and all i see is an "object object" how to do this within a template

Comment: did you try with 'triple-stash' `{{{` ? because then handlebars will not try to escape values and try to convert toString().

Comment: Copied and pasted my friend :) although I got a different approach

Comment: for me to see the object I needed to register a helper in my app.js: `hbs.registerHelper('json', (object) => JSON.stringify(object));` then in my view `{{{json .}}}`