# Accessing SQL object with handlebars to render on screen

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js, mysqljs

I'm building a bookstore app am using an SQL database with the mysqljs module i can fetch all books from database but i want to access one book and display its details.

I fetch the book object by its id and i display it in the console

book details route:

```
/* GET Book Details page. */
router.get('/details/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    var query = db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        var model = {result: result}
        res.render('shop/details', { title: 'Books', model });
    });
});
```

displays this on the console

[this is what the console displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD8wg.png)

in my handlebars code i wrote

```
<h1 class="text-center">Book Details Here</h1>
<h3> Your Book Name is {{this.BookName}}</h3>
```

but it only displays "Your Book Name is " without the book name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template, is expecting a Book object as a context and in your sample code you are passing it a result key which is mapped into an array containing the book object.

Here is how I usually debug such issues:
I would pass an object literal as a context just to make sure the render method works as I expect.

```
res.render('shop/details', { title: 'Books', {BookName: 'Season of migration to the north',id: 198} });
```

if this work, then you need to change the model that you pass to the page. so instead you will be passing request[0];

if this does not work, I would log the entire context object to the template to debug it. this post should help you how to do so: [Display Handlebars.js context in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231633/display-handlebars-js-context-in-a-template?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Good Luck!